# mysql query with string variables

Tags: mysql, string

I made a procedure that loops through a table of string names from "another_table" and I'm using those strings to make a query to a different table "inputOrders" but instead of returning numbers, all I get is my inputted string back.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS x1;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE retrieveOrderTotal()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE temp VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "";
    declare stuff CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM another_table;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    open stuff;
    getColumn: LOOP
            FETCH stuff INTO temp;
            IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE getColumn;
            END IF;
            select temp from inputOrders;
        END LOOP getColumn;
    close stuff;
End
//
```

variable another_table has :

```
5:_WKLY_SPCL_1
10:_WKLY_SPCL_1
15:_WKLY_SPCL_1
20:_WKLY_SPCL_1
```

and inputOrders have:

```
    5:_WKLY_SPCL_1
   ------------------
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table, ';');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```